# ¿Dónde verificar conexión a Internet?

Tags: android

quisiera su ayuda, he venido aprendiendo android he logrado hacer parsers de xmls, pero siempre el problema es la conexión a internet, cuando no la tiene hasta ahora las aplicaciones se cierran. Entonces: ¿Dónde debo hacer la verificación de conexión a internet?, en el adaptador, en el parser, en el fragment que une el adapter con el parser?.

Esto me viene dando dolor de cabeza por no logro hacerlo bien.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se supone que vas a llenar tu Adapter con datos previamente obtenidos y parseados de archivos .xml los cuales descargas de internet.

> ¿Dónde debo hacer la verificación de conexión a internet?, en el
>   adaptador, en el parser, en el fragment que une el adapter con el
>   parser?.

Lo correcto es verificar si tienes conexión a internet antes de realizar la descarga y ejecutar un parser, la razón? debes de validar para realizar o no la tarea de descargar y parsear los archivos.

Puedes usar este método para validar:

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
           NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR");
                    return true;
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI");
                    return true;
                }  else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)){
                    Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    return false;

}
```

<strike>Antiguo método:</strike>

```
private static ConnectivityManager manager;

public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

y lo usarias de esta forma:

```
if(isOnline(getApplicationContext()){
    //realiza descarga y parsing de datos.
}else{
   //Puedes mostrar un Toast indicando que no existe conectividad.
   Toast.makeText(app.getBaseContext(), "No existe conexión!", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Gracias lo voy a probar.