# NetworkInfor.IsConnected() retorna true cuando en realidad no se estableció la conexión

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

Estoy implementando un BroadcastReceiver para que cada vez que obtenga conexión
a Internet ***establecida*** (Wifi y Datos) lance una solicitud una Api Rest.
El BroadcastReceiver funciona, con la salvedad que `NetworkInfor.isConnected()` retorna verdadero cuando la conexión se esta realizando.

NetworkUtil

```
public class NetworkUtil {

  public static Boolean getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
      ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
              .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

      NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;

      if(cm != null)
          activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      // activeNetwork.isConnected() retorna verdadero pero la conexión no se estableció
      return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
  }
}
```

BroadcastReceiver

```
 public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private NetworkChange mListener;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
      if(mListener != null)

      mListener.onNetworkChange(NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context)); 
  }

  public void setListener(NetworkChange listener){
      mListener = listener;
  }

  public interface NetworkChange{
      void onNetworkChange(Boolean isConnected);
  }
}
```

Activity

```
private NetworkChangeReceiver mNetworkChangeReceiver;

mNetworkChangeReceiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
mNetworkChangeReceiver.setListener(this);


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final IntentFilter newFilter = new IntentFilter();
    newFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");

    registerReceiver(mNetworkChangeReceiver, newFilter);
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    unregisterReceiver(mNetworkChangeReceiver);
}

@Override
public void onNetworkChange(Boolean isConnected) {
    //Si hay conexión lanzo la solicitud con getListConstact(this)
    if(isConnected)
        mViewModel.getListConstact(this);
}
```

Comment: Una pregunta: ¿la solicitud a la API la haces por medio de `AsyncTask` o por medio de `Volley`?

Comment: @A.Cedano lo por medio de una interfaz con retrofit.

Comment: No conozco Retrofit. Preguntaba porque en mi App yo hago peticiones API por medio de `Volley` y manejo los errores (también los de conexión) en el `onErrorResponse`, combinando con una clase ayudadora en la que manejo los posibles errores que puedan ocurrir al hacer la petición...

Comment: ... Por ejemplo: `@Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyErrorHelper errorVolley = new VolleyErrorHelper();
                        String sError = VolleyErrorHelper.getMessage(error, getApplicationContext());
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + sError);
                        mTextView.setText(Utils.fromHtml(sError));
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }`. [Ver](https://www.javatips.net/api/VolleyPlus-master/library/src/com/android/volley/error/VolleyErrorHelper.java)

Comment: @A.Cedano si, tuve que llegar a esa solución, filtro el tipo de error y de ahí modifico la UI. Quería saber el por que no puedo saber con certeza cuando hay internet por el wifi, ya que con los datos, no sucede.

Comment: Yo choqué contra ese escollo, al  igual que tú, al principio, porque tengo una App que depende de internet para funcionar, entonces yo debo verificar que hay conexión antes de lanzar cualquier petición. Me da la impresión de que en muchos ejemplos que pululan por la red el problema era enfocado *al revés*. O sea, ¿por qué en vez de verificar si hay conexión no se verifica si hay un problema? Es lo que hago, a través de los métodos `isNetworkProblem` y `isServerProblem`. Si uno de ellos es `true`, entonces paso a saber **cuál es el problema**. Esto es particulamente importante para ...

Comment: ... cuestiones como el Wi-Fi. Ya que una cosa es que haya señal Wi-Fi y otra muy distinta es que haya conexión a internet. El router puede estar encendido, emitiendo una señal Wi-Fi, pero el cable ADSL puede estar desconectado, entonces hay Wi-Fi, pero no hay internet. ¿Hay que romperse la cabeza verificando primero si hay Wi-Fi y luego si hay internet? Pues no: **vayamos a verificar directamente si hay algún problema y luego determinemos qué problema es**. Si por cualquier motivo  interesa conocer el problema específico es posible, usando `error instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que tomar en cuenta que para tener una conexion satistfactoria y debes tener conectividad y esta debe estar disponible, en el caso de tu còdigo estas verificando si estas conectado, pero no si esta disponible la conexión:

```
return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
```

Deberìa ser mediante [isAvailable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isAvailable()) que indica si la conectividad a la red esta disponible:

```
return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isAvailable() && activeNetwork.isConnected();
```

---

Este es un ejemplo de un mètodo para [verificar conectividad y disponibilidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22534/d%C3%B3nde-verificar-conexi%C3%B3n-a-internet/22551#22551):

```
private static ConnectivityManager manager;

public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: Al asignar -1 seria de gran ayuda  agregar un comentario acerca de porque se considera esta respuesta incorrecta.

Comment: No fui el que puso el -1, pero desde mi lado puedo decir que eh probado esta solución y seguia con el mismo problema. Por eso opte por la solucion de A. Cedano.